# Bootstrap collapse only works once

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I have created an accordion with bootstrap collapse. There are certain elements in accordion that alternate on expansion on click of the particular element. The following markup is created:

```
    <div class="accordion" id="accordion2">

        <div class="accordion-group">
            <div class="accordion-heading">
                <a class="accordion-toggle" href="#collapse-0" id="0" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2">
                   User Visits
                </a>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse-0" class="accordion-body collapse in">
                <div class="accordion-inner">
                    Collapsible <br/>
                    Collapsible <br/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="accordion-group">                   
            <div class="accordion-heading">
                <a class="accordion-toggle" href="#collapse-1" id="1" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2">
                    Points
                </a>
            </div>                  
            <div id="collapse-1" class="accordion-body collapse">
                <div class="accordion-inner">
                    Collapsible <br/>
                    Collapsible <br/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

The problem is that after the page loads the first click on a particular element results in successful expansion of the `.accordion-body .collapse` block but successive calls do not result into any expansion.

The expansion results due to addition of a class called `in` dynamically. Even on the successive clicks on accordion elements the inspection shows the flipping of the `in` class as it should be but in spite of that the element doesn't expand.

Comment: You may have some kind of conflict on the page, causing the error - what javascript do you have? The markup above works perfectly here, inserted on a blank page.

Comment: I cannot figure out what kind of conflict I could have. Actually there are more than two elements and any one chosen for the first time expands and the subsequent calls dont. Not even the initally expanded element. It works perfect even here: http://jsfiddle.net/uycBa/35/

Comment: :) logically there must be a conflict - do you use "0", "1" etc as id's elsewhere? (Note, it is generally not adviceable to id elements as numbers, even though most browsers accept this it is illegal http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name) You are welcome to post the whole page / markup, incl javascript.

Comment: Have you looked at the javascript console? It sounds like your javascript might be dying after the first expand? `View > Developer > JavaScript Console`.

Its also possible that you have multiple accordians on the page, and are using the same id for the accordian's components, which is causing jquery's selector to fail, or select the wrong element, leading to failure to collapse the accordion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've figured out the problem. Actually the collapse jquery plugin requires the inclusion of `bootstrap-transition` plugin. I tried with either 'only' `bootstrap-collapse` that caused the above problem or a full `bootstrap.js` that caused other issues.

Comment: I think you should accept your answer, so others know that this is the correct solution. This worked for me.

Comment: My problem was including the transition plugin but not the collapse plugin! Your answer still helped me.

Comment: How do you include the transition plugin? Where do you specify that?